# What is the right ball-park in a sub-space?

Tags: analysis

In a proof of the theorem, "A sub-space, Y, of a totally bounded space X is totally bounded",  a covering of X by a finite number of balls, B(x, r/2), is divided into balls that meet Y and those that do not.   From each ball that meets Y, a point y is chosen and another set of balls, B(y; r), is defined.  Since the first set covers X and therefore Y, the second finite set of twice the radius also covers Y.   The proof continues with their intersections with Y and asserts that the finite set of balls, B(y; r) ^ Y, lie within the subspace, and make Y totally bounded. QED.  Now, my perhaps trivial question:  "Ball" seems to imply something spherical, and
B(y; r) ^ Y is not.  The definition of totally bounded that I have reads "a finite covering by open balls", not "a finite covering by open sets", as for example,  B(y; r) ^ Y, which may not be spherical.  Am I slicing this too finely?

Comment: Fenway Park? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general definition of totally bounded can be often phrased in terms of $\epsilon$-nets.
Given a metric space $X$, a subset $E$ and some $\epsilon>0$ We call $N^{\epsilon}$ an $\epsilon$-net of $E$ if for any $x \in E$ there exists some $y \in N^{\epsilon}$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$.

A set is totally bounded if it admits a finite $\epsilon$-net for any $\epsilon >0$.

In your case, sure, the intersections may not be balls when seen from the perspective of the big space $X$, but for the subspace $Y$, by all means the intersections produce "balls" even if they aren't inherently spherical because of the weird structure of $Y$. Rephrasing totally bounded-ness in terms of $\epsilon$-nets not lets you see that it is the distances that really matter, and not quite the shape of the sets you are covering with (although, yes surely the definition you gave is equivalent to the one stated in my answer - and it should be possible to extract "balls" from your intersection that agree with my statement about $\epsilon$-nets). It may also be fruitful to see this as the inherited topology in some sense, to get more of an intuitive feeling.

Comment: I am happy to note another way of expressing totally bounded that avoids the sphericity question.